# Array de caracteres não gravam da forma correta

Tags: java, array, caracteres

Eu estou fazendo um programa para criptografar de acordo com a Cifra de César, em Java. Eu me deparei com o seguinte problema no código:

```
package projects;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Projects {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String palavraLida = "";

        System.out.println("Digite a palavra que você quer criptografar:");
            palavraLida = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Digite a chave para o processo (0 - 25)");
        int chaveString = scanner.nextInt();

        char[] palavraGerada = new char[palavraLida.length()];

        int index = 0;

        if(chaveString <= 25 && chaveString >=0){
            for (int i = 0; i < palavraLida.length(); i++) {
                if (palavraLida.toCharArray()[i] == ' ') {
                 palavraGerada[i] = '#';   // Se for um espaco, cria uma hashtag na string de saída
                }else{
                    //Se não for, checa de acordo com o alfabeto
                   for (int j = 0; j < palavraLida.length(); j++) {
                       if (palavraGerada[i] == alphabet[j]) {
                          index = j + chaveString;
                          if(index >= 26){
                              index = index - 26;
                          }
                          palavraGerada[i] = alphabet[index];//Grava na array de saída de acordo com a variável correspondente
                       }
                   }                 
                } 
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Chave inválida.\n");
        }

          System.out.println(palavraGerada);

    }
}
```

A primeira checagem do loop FOR (que checa se o caractere é um espaço), funciona corretamente). Já, no else, para caracteres que não são um espaço, não funciona corretamente, já que no array de saída não fica gravado o caractere correspondente

Exemplo de execução do programa:

[image: Percebam que os espaços são inseridos corretamente]

Comment: Olhando seu código por aqui, percebi que o primeiro `if` dentro do segundo `for` onde `palavraGerada[i] == alphabet[j]` a "palavraGerada" na sua posição "i" está sempre em branco, sendo assim nunca será igual ao seu alfabeto. Não seria ali o local para colocar a `palavraLida`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alterações:

`palavraGerada[i]` substituida por `palavraLida.toCharArray()[i]`

`for (int j = 0; j < palavraLida.length(); j++)` substituido por `for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++)`

Solução:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {

        char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String palavraLida = "";

        System.out.println("Digite a palavra que você quer criptografar:");
        palavraLida = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Digite a chave para o processo (0 - 25)");
        int chaveString = scanner.nextInt();

        char[] palavraGerada = new char[palavraLida.length()];

        int index = 0;

        if (chaveString <= 25 && chaveString >= 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < palavraLida.length(); i++) {
                if (palavraLida.toCharArray()[i] ==' ') {
                    palavraGerada[i] = '#';   // Se for um espaco, cria uma hashtag na string de saída
                } else {
                    //Se não for, checa de acordo com o alfabeto
                    for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
                        if (palavraLida.toCharArray()[i] == alphabet[j]) {
                            index = j + chaveString;
                            if (index >= 26) {
                                index = index - 26;
                            }
                            palavraGerada[i] = alphabet[index];//Grava na array de saída de acordo com a variável correspondente
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Chave inválida.\n");
        }

        System.out.println(palavraGerada);
    }
```

Comment: Deu certo, um erro minúsculo, haha. Muito obrigado!